# 3D view's "view selected" (numpad .) problem after 2.79

Tags: 3d-view

This feature works but not as good as before updating to 2.79.

When I want to zoom to the current bone I am working with, using "view selected" — it just zooms to the center of the whole object. Before 2.79 I was able to zoom to each bone and then rotate camera around it so I could focus on it comfortably.

Am I missing something? Is there a setting somewhere to enable what I want or it is a bug?

Peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it easier for anyone else by furthering what Ignac said in his answer, **N Properties Panel** (press "N") >**View**>**Lock to Object**. Click the X in field.

[image: 1]

Thanks, Ignac!

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I was accidentally locked onto the object in "N" properties and that caused this problem.